# How to bind the value from ng-repeat in this DIV tag to <a></a>

Tags: angularjs, query-string, angularjs-directive

See i have template like this in my directive

```
templete = 
    '<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">'+
      '<a href="www.localhost:3000#/?email=contact.email&phone=contact.phoneno">{{contact.email}}</a>'+
    '</div>'
```

contacts is array like this

```
contacts[
 {email:a457@yahoo.com,
 phoneno:8976555},
 {email:a4ded57@yahoo.com,
 phoneno:89656562}
]
```

But i am not getting the values of the contact array in query string.

How to get that values in query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template should probably be:

```
template = 
    '<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">'+
        '<a href="www.localhost:3000#/?email={{contact.email}}&phone={{contact.phoneno}}">{{contact.email}}</a>'+
    '</div>'
```